# Cache only a single step in sklearn's Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I want to use UMAP in my sklearn's Pipeline, and I would like to cache that step to speed things up. However, since I have custom Transformer, [the suggested method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html) doesn't work.

Example code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from umap import UMAP
from hdbscan import HDBSCAN
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
X = iris.drop(columns='species')
y = iris.species

@FunctionTransformer
def transform_something(iris):
    iris = iris.copy()
    iris['sepal_sum'] = iris.sepal_length + iris.sepal_width
    return iris

cachedir = mkdtemp()
pipe = Pipeline([
                 ('transformer', transform_something),
                 ('umap', UMAP()),
                 ('hdb', HDBSCAN()),
                ],
                memory=cachedir
            )

pipe.fit_predict(X)
```

If you run this, you will get a `PicklingError`, saying it cannot pickle the custom transformer. But I only need to cache the UMAP step. Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: Under the hood, sklearn uses joblib. Maybe you could use this lib directly? https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/memory_basic_usage.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the cleanest, but you could nest pipelines?

```py
pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ('transformer', transform_something),
        ('the_rest', Pipeline([
            ('umap', UMAP()),
            ('hdb', HDBSCAN()),
        ], memory=cachedir))
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

What also works is, instead of using the `FunctionTransformer`, writing your custom transform function from scratch like this:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class transform_something(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X = X.copy()
        X['sepal_sum'] = X.sepal_length + X.sepal_width
        return X
```

Unfortunately it is a bit more code, but it is picklable.

Comment: might need `y=None` added as `fit(self,X,y=None)` and `transform(self,X,y=None)` in some cases as I think it can throw errors